# convert string date with 3 char month

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, varchar

I have a varchar column in a DB with dates. In C#, with a SQL Select, I'm trying to convert the string (example: 'Apr-10-2009') (MMM-dd-yyyy) to a datetime but gives:

> varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I realize it has to be the 3 char month but not sure what convert method I need to do this.

Note: This is an old legacy DB that I inherited. I was amazed at the poor choice of varchar field types for these date values instead of datetime.

```
SELECT convert(datetime, dbo.EffectiveDate, 100) from Employees
```

or

```
SELECT convert(datetime, dbo.EffectiveDate) from Employees
```

comes from example: `SELECT convert(datetime, 'Oct 23 2012 11:01AM', 100)`

or

```
SELECT convert(datetime, 'Oct 23 2012 11:01AM')
```

even though field values don't include the time part, I tried them

Employee table:

EffectiveDate varchar field

Dec-12-2006

Oct-24-2006

..

..

etc

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show your [MCVE] at least? Also you look like a victim of [choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type). You should **not** store your `DateTime` values as a `varchar`. Most of RDMS's has date related data types which is exactly what they are for.

Comment: Can you show your sql sentence and how the data is stored?

Comment: Add some sample data you wants to convert to date as per mentioned format.

Comment: Tag your question with the database oyu are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do. That is if the varchar date column all follow this format: (MMM-dd-yyyy)

```
select convert(datetime,convert(date, replace('Apr-10-2009', '-', ' ')))
```

Outputs: 2009-04-10 00:00:00.000

Comment: I appreciate your your suggestion, thanks!
It appears to be working!
I will continue to test

Answer (score 0):

The internationally recognised date format order is yyyy-mm-dd, use this layout and it will work better

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

e.g.

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '2012 Oct 23  11:01AM')
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion too. I will try this out